# Units when replicating a digital call with vanilla spread

Tags: binary-options

This is an embarassingly basic question, but in the course of studying windmill adjustment in binary FX options, I unexpectedly got stuck figuring out the correct units. Say we have a domestic binary call ("cash-or-nothing") and we replicate with a tight call spread around the strike. Theoretically, we have

$$
C_b \approx \frac{C_v(K - \epsilon)-C_v(K + \epsilon)}{2\epsilon}
$$

for $h \to 0$. The denominator and numerator here share the same units, right? So the result is unitless, but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's a probability, so it must be unitless. The dollars you get is through the notional, eg you get 1 dollar if the asset is above a certain strike.

Comment: @FridoRolloos oh, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FridoRolloos quick follow-up: is the discount factor $e^{-r_f \tau}$ in the analytic formula not in dollars?

Comment: A power series (such as exp function) must be dimensionless. Can't add dollars and dollars^2 and dollars^n etc.

Comment: I tell all my imaginary students to write down all the SDEs they know and figure out the dimension of each variable and parameter in the SDEs. It helps.

Comment: @FridoRolloos I never thought about it like that, great perspective! The reason why I saw the DF as a dollar amount is because some bond valuation text books take it to the price (NPV) of a zero coupon bond.

Comment: Last comment: well it is the dimensionless factor applied to the principal of 1 dollar to obtain the current price of a ZC.

Comment: @FridoRolloos got it, thanks!